# Display a Single location that have two words in a URL

Tags: seo, url

I have to show locations in a URL. The mentioned location has two words. Salvage fort

What is the ideal URL structure?

//test. com/search/aza/salvage%20fort-to-missipi

//test. com/search/aca/salvagefort-to-missipi

//test. com/search/avr/salvage-fort-to-missipi

Answer (score 1):

A "-" or not a "-" does not affect SEO. The URL is only a minor indication of what the page is about. Not enough to qualify a page for the word in the URL. for a search,

> IE a search for ABC, XYZ would not show results for a URL of example.com/ABC/XYZ unless the page itself had both ABC and XYZ on the page.
>
> ABC does not qualify as a keyword for the XYZ page but it does aid in search for ABC, XYZ when ABC exists on the XYZ page.

A %20 is not a problem either but some software on the user's side may have problems or sites where you can post a link.

aza, aca, and avr would also have no SEO effect due to URL. The benefit of those is for content creation or If you want to scan your log files --

```
grep "/search/avr/" website.log
```

-- or otherwise get stats on sections of the site to know what sections are working well and what sections are not.

There would be a SEO benefit to having the aza, aca, and avr as parent pages that link to the pages under them. And it is typical to arrange links and URLs in the same fashion. Hence you will find advice about SEO to have that structure. But its not the URL structure it is the parent linking to child pages structure. I for one prefer the URL structure of using the parent directories with supporting content as directories under it as I can functionally get the stats of the whole cluster much faster.